# JS : how to write a function witch accept another function as parameter and return a function

Tags: javascript

I ve to write a function **myFunction** that accepts another function (**myCallbackFunction**) as parameter .

myFunction would return a resulted function **myResultFunction()** which calls the callback

`myResultFunction` is called every **100ms**

the callback function ; `myCallbackFunction` should be called at most once every **300 ms**

it's something like this :

```
function myFunction(paramFunction){
  return setInterval( myResultFunction(paramFunction); , 100);
  // paramFunction is the callback taht should be called at once 300ms  
}

function myResultFunction(paramfunction){
      return setInterval( paramfunction(); , 300);
}
myFunction(myCallbackFunction);
```

i need to adapt to have this behaviour :

- **myFunction** is called initially , so **myCallbackFunction** has not yet been called in the last 300 ms
- **at t= 0ms** : `myResultFunction();`
- **at t=100ms** : `myResultFunction();`
- **at t=200ms** : `myResultFunction();`
- **at t=300 ms** : `myCallbackFunction() ;`
- this behaviour should **loop** indefinetly so that the first time the callback mybe called

**Suggestions** to write **myFunction** , **myCallbackFunction** and **myResultFunction** ??**

Comment: do you have a practical example?

Comment: You need to give an example for the use case here. At least from my end, I don't see any utility in this: unless there is a somewhere that keeps calling `myFunction()`, why do you need to return a different function based on a timestamp? In one way or another, I don't think you want to return the function: but simply to call a different function based on the timestamp, am I right?

Comment: i ve updated the example and the purpose so that it maybe cleaner

Comment: You may want to look at this library to get some ideas: https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce

Comment: This looks like default "throttle" interview/homework question. Could you provide a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it? Otherwise this question is off-topic on SO, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var timer = 0;
var step = 100;
var callbackStep = 300;

function myFunction(callback){
  setInterval( function() {
    if(timer >= callbackStep && timer % callbackStep === 0) {
      callback()
    } else {
    // myResultFunction(); dont really need this, but can be called.
    }
    timer += step
  }, step);
}

myFunction(function(){console.log(`Once every ${callbackStep}ms. Current ${(timer ? timer : 100) / (step / 100 * callbackStep)}`);});
```

Comment: that's great , except that lakcs something ; initially it should start by calling the callback (console.log(123)  , i mean  , just for the first time it should print it

Comment: So change the if statement to read:
`if(timer === 0 ||  timer >= callbackStep && timer % callbackStep === 0) {`

Answer (score 3):

This is when you actually take advantage of [iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), available in ES6. Basically, `myFunction` will be the iterator that will iterate on indefinitely in a `while(true)` loop. For each iteration, you increment the iteration by 1. Every 4thiteration will return the result of `myCallbackFunction()`, otherwise it will return the result of `myResultFunction()`.

Once you instantiate your iterator, you can then call the `.next()` method on it at the desired interval: in your case, you want it to step every 100ms. I have slightly adjusted the proof-of-concept below to step every **1000ms** so that you can actually see what is going on:

```js
function* myFunction(callback) {
    let count = 1;
    while (true) {
      let output;
      if (count % 4 === 0)
        output = callback();
      else
        output = myResultFunction();
      
      count++;
      yield output;
    }
}

function myResultFunction() {
  return 'myResultFunction(): called every count';
}

function myCallbackFunction() {
  return 'myCallbackFunction(): called at every fourth count';
}

var iteratorFunction = myFunction(myCallbackFunction);

// Run the first time without delay
console.log(iteratorFunction.next().value);

// Step to the next iteration every n seconds
window.setInterval(() => {
  console.log(iteratorFunction.next().value);
}, 1000);
```

Update: Looks like OP wants to invoke the `callback()` method first. If that's the case, `let count = 1` in the snippet above should be changed to `let count = 0`:

```js
function* myFunction(callback) {
    let count = 0;
    while (true) {
      let output;
      if (count % 4 === 0)
        output = callback();
      else
        output = myResultFunction();
      
      count++;
      yield output;
    }
}

function myResultFunction() {
  return 'myResultFunction(): called every count';
}

function myCallbackFunction() {
  return 'myCallbackFunction(): called at every fourth count';
}

var iteratorFunction = myFunction(myCallbackFunction);

// Run the first time without delay
console.log(iteratorFunction.next().value);

// Step to the next iteration every n seconds
window.setInterval(() => {
  console.log(iteratorFunction.next().value);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: that's great , except that lakcs something ; initially it should start by calling the callback (myCallbackFunction) , i mean , just for the first time it should print it

Comment: @firasKoubaa Then just change `let count = 1` to `let count = 0`. That should call the `callback` function passed as an argument  in the first iteration instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the functions in an array in the wanted order and use a closure over the index and increment this index after each call. Adjust if necessary.

```js
function a() {
    console.log('a');
}

function b() {
    console.log('b');
}

var fn = [a, a, a, b];

setInterval((i => () => {
    fn[i]();
    i++;
    i %= fn.length;
})(1), 100);

fn[0]();
```